# Ext JS LoadRawData TotalProperty not being set

Tags: extjs, extjs4

I am loading data into a gridpanel via LoadRawData but total property does not get set.

App.GP.getStore().loadRawData(obj);

To the end I have overridden the LoadRawData method to force it to set but this still did not work.

```
 Ext.define('App.patch.app.Store', {
    override: 'Ext.data.Store',

    loadRawData: function (data, append) {
        var me = this,
         result = me.proxy.reader.read(data),
         records = result.records;

        if (result.success) {
            me.totalCount = result.total;
            me.loadRecords(records, { addRecords: append });
            me.fireEvent('load', me, records, true);
        }
    }
});
```

I am loading in 3 records for a pagesize of 3 but setting the totalCount to 8.

I debugged this line by line and confirmed that me.totalCount gets set to 8 but then when the pagegrid loads the display message in the paging toolbar is Displaying Offices 1 - 3 of 3.

It should be saying 1 - 3 of 8.

This is my gridpanel

```
pitem.Add(Html.X().GridPanel()
                             .ID("GP")
                             .Title(_AllOffices.SelectOffices_Text)
                             .Header(true)
                             .Border(false)
                             .Frame(true)
                             .Store(st => st.Add(Html.X().Store()
                                                        .ID("Store")
                                                        .AutoLoad(true)
                                                        .RemoteSort(false)
                                                        .IsPagingStore(true)
                                                        .RemotePaging(true)                
                                                        .AutoDataBind(true)                                                           
                                                        .PageSize(3)
                                                        .Reader(x=>x.Add(Html.X().JsonReader().Root("data")))
                                                        .Model(Html.X().Model().Fields(new ModelField("Id")))                                                                                                                                                                                                        
                             ))
                             .ColumnModel(columnModel => columnModel.Columns.Add(Html.X().Column().Text("Id").DataIndex("Id").Flex(1)))
                             .SelectionModel(Html.X().CheckboxSelectionModel())               
                             .BottomBar(bar => bar.Add(Html.X().PagingToolbar()
                                                           .DisplayInfo(true)
                                                           .HideRefresh(true)
                                                           .Listeners(x=> x.BeforeChange.Fn="GetSelectedRows").Listeners(x=> x.Change.Fn="CheckRows")                                                               
                                                           .DisplayMsg(_AllOffices.DisplayingOffices_Text + " {0} - {1} of {2}"))
                             )
                             .View(view => view.Add(Html.X().GridView()))
                   );
```

I should also add the I add in a lot of columns and fields dynamically before the loadrawdata call but this all works fine.

Comment: The default totalProperty of the proxy reader is "total".